# show the current location on Google maps using Maps Api

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an Activity named as `HomeActivity.kt` where I have `BottomNavBar`.

My `HomeActivity.kt` is as below.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.harry.pennysaver.R
import com.harry.pennysaver.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.home -> replaceFragment(HomeFragment())
                R.id.shopping_cart -> replaceFragment(ShoppingCartFragment())
                R.id.settings -> replaceFragment(SettingsFragment())
                else -> {}
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }
}
```

The `BottomNavBar` has 3 fragments named as `HomeFragment`, `ShoppingCartFragment` and `SettingsFragment`.
I am implementing the Google Maps in `HomeFragment`.

Have a look on `HomeFragment.kt`

```
import android.Manifest
import android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
import android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.harry.pennysaver.base.BaseViewBindingFragment
import com.harry.pennysaver.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

class HomeFragment : BaseViewBindingFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>(FragmentHomeBinding::inflate),
    OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private lateinit var mapView: MapView
    private lateinit var googleMap: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var currentLocation: Location
    private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

    companion object {
        const val LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.toolbar.toolbarTitle.text = "Search"
        mapView = binding.mapView

        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireActivity())
        getCurrentLocationUser()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mapView.onPause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mapView.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onMapReady(p0: GoogleMap) {
        googleMap = p0
        googleMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
        val currentLatLng = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude)
        placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLng)
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng, 12f))
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java", ReplaceWith(
        "super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)",
        "com.harry.pennysaver.base.BaseViewBindingFragment"
    )
    )
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        when(requestCode) {
            LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE -> if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getCurrentLocationUser()
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun getCurrentLocationUser() {
        if (
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION), LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE)
            return
        }
        val getLocation = fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(requireActivity()) { location ->
            if(location != null) {
                currentLocation = location
                mapView.getMapAsync(this)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLng: LatLng) {
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(currentLatLng)
        markerOptions.title("$currentLatLng")
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
    }

    override fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker) = false
}
```

I am trying to fetch the current location on map. If the location permission is given then map has to place the marker where I am currently living (Germany). But map is showing the location of `US, MountainView`??. Also have a look over the below video.

Also in `onRequestPermissionsResult` is deprecated for fragment. So what is the different alternative for that if we use in fragment? I have seen some answers where used `registerForActivityResult()` but how I use in my code, I am learning this.

[image]

Comment: Have you changed the location in the simulator, otherwise it's the default location of it being shown.

Comment: @NilsKähler: When user gives location permission, emulator will take the current location, I think. And other thing I have noticed that on real device `onMapReady()` is not called at all?

Comment: @NilsKähler: You were right. When I have made started working on real device I found that its showing the default location on simulator.